# Coding Dijkstra's algorithm without modifying original Node

Tags: swift, algorithm

I have a working version of Dijkstra's algorithm in my language of choice - in this case Swift.

As you may know, the algorithm requires that you place temporary labels on nodes - but is it possible to implement WITHOUT changing the original class. For reference here is a cut down node class, but this question is not language dependent as I would just like to know how this can be implemented without changing the original class.

```
class Node: Hashable {
    var nodes = [Int:[Int]]()
    var children = [Node]()
}
```

Comment: One option would be to store a map of `[Node:Int]` for the scores

Comment: Please correct me if I understand the question wrong, you want to label a class named node without changing the attributes of it. So why not to a binary structure like HashMap in Java. A mapping will work for it I guess. You can map every node object with an unique number.

Comment: You **do not** need to store anything inside of the `Node`, you actually do not need to know anything about `Node` itself. Only thing you need to know is distance between nodes (if they're linked).

Comment: Which is the question, effectively. WHERE would you store the distance for each node? Just saying you don't need to is effectively saying you can do it, but not saying how. Great.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One semi-hacky solution would be to use associated objects:

```swift
fileprivate var labelKey: UInt8 = 0
extension Node {
    var label: Int {
        get {
            return objc_getAssociatedObject(self, &labelKey) as? Int ?? 0
        }
        set {
            objc_setAssociatedObject(self, &labelKey, newValue, .OBJC_ASSOCIATION_RETAIN_NONATOMIC)
        }
    }
}
```

This way you don't alter the original class.

Comment: Shouldn't it be `&labelKey`  ?

Comment: @MartinR yeah, missed that when I wrote the answer. Thanks for the observation, updated the answer.

Comment: Why is `Int` `retained`?

Comment: @user28434 Swift's `Int` gets converted under the hood to `NSNumber`, which needs to be retained.